# Minha aplicação em React da erro de página não encontrada se eu digitar a url

Tags: react, react-native

Olá quando eu digito a segunda url no meu local o Route funciona levando para página solicitada, porém quando eu fiz o build hospedei e repeti o mesmo procedimento a mesma não funciona dando página não encontrada alguém sabe informar como corrijo esse problema? Segue em Anexo a imagem do meu App.js.

Comment: Problema resolvido, precisei criar um arquivo .htaccess na pasta public simples e fácil.
Porém em outro servidor que estava com o mesmo problema eu criei um arquivo chamado "_redirects" e dentro adicionai a linha " /* /index.html 200 " também tive sucesso. Obs: Duas soluções que resolvem o mesmo problema em servidores de hospedagens diferentes.

Comment: Olá, você poderia mostrar seu código do componente Routes ?

Answer (score 1):

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import RouteHandler from './components/RouteHandler';

import Home from './pages/Home';
import Leitura from './pages/Leitura';
import Admin from './pages/Admin';
import NotFound from './pages/NotFound';
import SignIn from './pages/SignIn';
import SignUp from './pages/SignUp';
import AddConteudo from './pages/AddConteudo';
import Listagem from './pages/Listagem';

export default () => {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <RouteHandler exact path="/">
                <Home />
            </RouteHandler>
            <RouteHandler exact path="/ad/:id">
                <Leitura />
            </RouteHandler>
            <RouteHandler private exact path="/admin">
                <Admin />
            </RouteHandler>
            <RouteHandler exact path="/signin">
                <SignIn />
            </RouteHandler>
            <RouteHandler exact path="/signup">
                <SignUp />
            </RouteHandler>
            <RouteHandler private exact path="/addconteudo">
                <AddConteudo />
            </RouteHandler>
            <RouteHandler exact path="/listagem">
                <Listagem />
            </RouteHandler> 
            <RouteHandler>
                <NotFound />
            </RouteHandler>
        </Switch>
    );
}

Observe que RouteHandler herda de outro componente Segue a baixo...

import React  from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { isLogged } from '../helpers/AuthHandler';

export default ({ children, ...rest }) => {
    let logged = isLogged();
    let autorizado = (rest.private && !logged) ? false : true;
    return (
        <Route 
            {...rest}
            render={ () => 
                autorizado ? children : <Redirect to="/entrar" />}
        />
    );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

coloca no htaccess:

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.html

Options -Indexes